# How to associate .CGI with PERL EPIC in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, perl

I am searching for a solution of how to associate .cgi extension with Perl language (to highlight syntax correctly) in Perl Epic under Eclipse 3.8.1 Linux x64? Currently it highlights only files with .pl extension. When opening .cgi or files without any extensions the Eclipse highlights them very different than Perl Epic is set up.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [create a new file association](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-13.htm?cp=0_4_1_27) and associate the "Epic Perl Editor" with it. Also see [Associating Files with the Perl Editor](http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch02s07.php) in the EPIC documentation, which says:

> Eclipse associates file extensions with editors. If another plug-in is
>   installed, the EPIC Perl Editor might not be used as the default
>   editor when opening *.pl, *.pm or *.cgi files. To associate these file
>   extensions with the Perl Editor, choose Window → Preferences... from
>   the Eclipse menu and select Workbench → File Associations. If the Perl
>   extensions are missing, they can be created by pressing the Add...
>   button. Select the Perl Editor from the list and press the Default
>   button.

Comment: Thank you! A little correction (perhaps for my version): Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations. Thanks!